accsess catalog from power BI
I'm trying to access the catalog from power BI which are present in databricks workspace  . But I could see only default catalog.
other catalogs are not visible while accessing from power BI.
Is there any permission that need be enabled? or any configuration?
enter image description here

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Databricks has created a "Unity Catalog" that exists above the database/schema level. Many SQL clients therefore do not understand how to connect and display the available Catalogs.
If you are connecting via JDBC, you can specify a particular catalog by adding a ConnCatalog parameter:

jdbc:databricks://dbc-123.cloud.databricks.com:443/default;transportMode=http;ssl=1; AuthMech=3;httpPath=/sql/1.0/warehouses/abc123;ConnCatalog=my_catalog;

You can also specify ConnSchema.
See: Driver capability settings for the Databricks JDBC Driver | Databricks on AWS

yes I tried to add catalog  by it's not working
